# Capture Backspace , is this a OK solution?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, uitextview

I having a hard time to capture the backspace button in a UITextView. 
I am trying to capture it in the method

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView 
         shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
```

I thought it was ok to do like this.

```
if([text isEqualToString:@"\b") {  // code ... }
```

But for some reason, when backspace is pressed  'text' is empty.
I know I can compare lenght of the UITextView but it isnt what I want to achieve.

So I found a solution to this.
If I look at '[text lenght]' every key on the defaultkeyboard returns >0 . Every key excepts the backspace wich is 0.  In that way i know when backspace is pressed.
I do this check.

```
if([text lenght] == 0) {   // BACKSPACE PRESSED   }
```

What is your opinion about this? -or can I do it in a better way?

EDIT:  As David Gelhar told me, this wont work cus CUT will trigger ([text lenght] == 0) aswell.

Anyone that can point me to the correct directions here?

Regards. 
- Martin

Comment: I have a Tableview each row containing a TextView. When Im at first row of TextView and cursor is at first charachter of the TextView , I should remove this row and add (if there is any) text to the row above, when im hit backspace button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should also test what happens when the user does a CUT...